# SSL connect error (LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to crates.io:443 )

Tags: curl, ssl

Today when I am using this cargo command in macOS Monteney to build the rust project:

```
cargo build
```

shows error like this:

```
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to crates.io:443 )
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to crates.io:443 )
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [35] SSL connect error (LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to crates.io:443 )
error: failed to download from `https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/tracing-core/0.1.26/download`

Caused by:
  [35] SSL connect error (LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to crates.io:443 )
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix it? I have already tried to install `curl-openssl` like this:

```
brew install curl-openssl
```

still could not fixed this problem.

Comment: Linking in https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8339 as having some possibilities to try (I cannot, at the moment)

Comment: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL means the underlying `connect()` call failed, not the SSL connection negotiation directly. Unfortunately the log output fails to give you what the underlying connect error was.